# Visual Studio VB.net executable do not open on another computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, build, executable, .net-framework-version

I'd like to create an executable for my VB.net project that interact with Catia V5.

Using the "build" function of Visual Studio, it creates a folder \bin\Debug with a .exe file, the file do open without any problem on the machine where I coded it, but if I send the debug folder to my second computer, nothing pops up when I click on the .exe file.

I also tried to click on the file named "WindowsApp1.application", a prompt ask me if I want to install the app but once I click on yes I get an error that looks kind of like this "Unable to download the app. Files are missing for the application. For assistance, contact the application vendor."

I don't know if the problem comes from here, but the app is using .NET Framework 4.7.2, and my second computer has .NET Framework 4.8, I didn't manage to downgrade to 4.7.2 to see if it would change something.

[image]

Comment: What does your application do when it opens? Have you looked at the event log to see if anything is getting logged about your application issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Catia V5 was not open on my second computer, it would then crash instantly (same behavior on the original computer). To fix that I added some kind of "check" in the code with a pop-up text asking to open Catia first.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)